# using variables from variable group in release tasks

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a variable group and set a variable there `CustomArtifactName` and have given the scope as Release
The value of this variable is set in build pipeline so it generates a unique name for artifacts

`Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CustomArtifactName]$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddhhmmss)"`

I can use this fine in build pipelline in yaml in `PublishPipelineArtifact@1` tasks like this

`'drop-pom-''$(CustomArtifactName)'`

But when I use the below in release pipeline `maven` tasks in `Maven POM File` field

`$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/cucumber-java-junit5-webapp/drop-pom-$(CustomArtifactName)/s/target/pom.xml`

I get

`##[error]Unhandled: Not found mavenPOMFile:`

I also tried to use this variable in `Download Pipeline Artifact` task but got similar result

How do I use variables from variable group in release tasks fields/properties? According to [this msdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch) we simply have to use `$(variableName)` but thats not working .

Comment: Can you share the important parts of your yaml file? Otherwise the answer will be quite vague.

Comment: Hi @user1207289. Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, when you reference the variable group in the build pipeline, you set the variable with new value.

The new value only applies to the build pipeline, it does not update the value of the variable in the variable group, so it will still use the old variable in the release pipeline. This could be the root cause of this issue.

To solve this issue , you need to add a Powershell task to run Rest API([Variablegroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedTask/Variablegroups/Update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)) to update the variable in variable group.

Here is the Powershell Script example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{organizationname}/{projectname}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{variablegroupid}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON = @'
{
  
  "variables": {
    "CustomArtifactName": {
      "value": "$(CustomArtifactName)"
    }

  },
  "type": "Vsts",
  "name": "{variablegroupname}",
  "description": "Updated variable group"

}
'@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method PUT -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
```

[image]

**Result:** The variable in variable group will update based on each build.

[image]

**Update:**

variable group id:

You could open the variable group in website and check the URL.

[image]

When the Powershell script runs successfully, the value of the variable will be passed to the variable in Variable Group.

Comment: I could locate most fields but where do I get `{variablegroupid}` from?

Comment: Got id, which came as `1` from `az cli`. But when I run the task i get `2021-05-12T22:22:04.6137194Z ##[error]Unhandled: Not found mavenPOMFile: D:\a\r1\a\cucumber-java-junit5-webapp\drop-pom-\s\target\pom.xml` in maven task .  Powershell script ran fine with a green check. I changed just this part in script `$url="https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/myProject/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/1?api-version=5.0-preview.1"` and ` "name": "var-group"` , which is my actual group name

Comment: I was expecting the variable to be replaced here `drop-pom-{CustomArtifactName}` , but it came as blank as in my previous comment

Comment: @user1207289 From your description, the Powershell task hasn't updated the Variable Group yet. You need to check the fields in Powershell script. For the variable group id, you could refer to my update.

Comment: It seems `$(CustomArtifactName)` in script is not updating , if I provide `"value": "someValue"`, i get powershell output correctly. Do you have an idea on how to use `$(CustomArtifactName)` in powershell ?

Comment: It is working now, needed to put the powershell task in build pipeline and not in release pipeline